# how to redirect to cart page if refreshed on checkout page magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to redirect the user to domainname.com/checkout/cart if user refreshes the site when on domainname.com/checkout.

The reason i want to do this is because whenever a user refreshes the page all the selection like shipping, payment method and credit card details are getting cleared and i have 4 steps checkout process unlike the default which is 2 steps.Also let me know if there is any solution to stop the clearing of selection in checkout process

Answer (score 0):

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Are you sure you wish to leave the page?";
}
(or)
$(window).on('load', function(){
    // your logic here`enter code here`
});

try above methods or u can add this code in js files which are used only in checkout page or onepage.phtml file because we cannot set the data using Magento default when a user refreshes the page.